# Wordpress Shortcode Not Displaying Results

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have been attempting to create my own shortcode for my Wordpress theme to make life a bit easier. Unfortunately I have run into issues with my code.

Below, the code in the Javascript section is what I have placed in my functions.php file, and in the HTML section is what I have placed on my page in Wordpress as the shortcode, however nothing seems to appear?

1: JAVASCRIPT

2: HTML

```js
function hire_equipment_func($atts) {
       extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'img' => 'no-img',
        'user' => 'no-user',
  'text' => 'no-text',
    ), $atts ) );

    if ( $atts['img'] == '' || $atts['user'] == '' || $atts['text'] == '' ) return; 

    $output =
 
  '<div>
   
   <div>' . $atts['img'] . '</div><br />
   
   <div>' . $atts['user'] . '</div>
   
   <div>' . $atts['text'] . '</div>
   
  </div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'hire_equipment', 'hire_equipment_func' );
```

```html
[hire_equipment img="" user="Test Float" text="Can be used anywhere"]
```

Any help with this issue would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Kind regards,
Jesse

Answer (score 1):

This will return nothing if one of the attributes is not set, and will return each attribute in a `div` otherwise.

```
   function hire_equipment_func($atts) {
        $atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);
        if (!isset($atts['img']) || !isset($atts['user']) || !isset($atts['text'])) return; 

        $output =
            '<div>        
                <div>' . $atts['img'] . '</div><br />
                <div>' . $atts['user'] . '</div>
                <div>' . $atts['text'] . '</div>
            </div>';

        return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'hire_equipment', 'hire_equipment_func' );
```

Comment: My code has changed to accommodate more information.

Below is the new code. I want it to work as in "if" certain attributes are full, display $output1. "if" it contains other certain attributes, display $output2.

Check it out and see if you know whats going wrong:

https://jsfiddle.net/6mjjadra/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hire_equipment_func($atts) {
       extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'img' => 'no-img',
        'user' => 'no-user',
  'text' => 'no-text',
    ), $atts ) );

    if ( $atts['img'] == 'no-img' || $atts['user'] == 'no-user' || $atts['text'] == 'no-text' ) return; 

    $output =
 
  '<div>
   
   <div>' . $atts['img'] . '</div><br />
   
   <div>' . $atts['user'] . '</div>
   
   <div>' . $atts['text'] . '</div>
   
  </div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'hire_equipment', 'hire_equipment_func' );
```

```html
[hire_equipment img="" user="Test Float" text="Can be used anywhere"]
```

Okay, for some reason I placed the same text from each attribute (e.g. 'no-img' from attribute 'img') into each text area in the IF statement, and it worked!

So I have answered my own question! However, I am still interested in wondering WHY that works the way it did. I am willing to mark the question as ANSWERED once someone helps me in understanding the concept reason behind it.

Thanks!
Jesse

Comment: I do have one other issue however. If I do not add anything in one of the attributes, it still displays on my web page. How can I remove sections that have no attribute data??

Comment: Use `isset` for each of them.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? Still learning Wordpress haha :) Thank you!

Comment: An example of using isset() is provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove sections that are not specified, so if you toss this snippet of PHP into your functions.php file (in your child theme, preferably):

```
function hire_equipment_func( $atts ) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts( 
            array(
                'img'    => 'no-img'
                , 'user' => 'no-user'
                , 'text' => 'no-text'
            )
            , $atts 
        ) 
    );

    $output = '<div>' . PHP_EOL;
    if( isset( $atts[ 'img' ]  ) ) { $output .= '    <div>' . $atts[ 'img' ]  . '</div><br>' . PHP_EOL; }
    if( isset( $atts[ 'user' ] ) ) { $output .= '    <div>' . $atts[ 'user' ] . '</div>'     . PHP_EOL; }
    if( isset( $atts[ 'text' ] ) ) { $output .= '    <div>' . $atts[ 'text' ] . '</div>'     . PHP_EOL; }
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'hire_equipment', 'hire_equipment_func' );
```

and place this WordPress shortcode on your page:

```
[hire_equipment img="" user="Test Float" text="Can be used anywhere"]
```

you will get:

```
　 
Test Float
Can be used anywhere
```

Example 2:

```
[hire_equipment img="/file/path/image.svg" user="Test Float" text="Can be used anywhere"]
```

yields

```
/file/path/image.svg

Test Float
Can be used anywhere
```

Example 3:

```
[hire_equipment img="/file/path/image.svg" text="Can be used anywhere"]
```

outputs

```
/file/path/image.svg

Can be used anywhere
```

Example 4:

```
[hire_equipment img="" user="" text=""]
```

shows

caused by that line break in your markup.

If you're wondering, PHP_EOL is a PHP constant denoting the correct 'End Of Line' symbol for your platform.